# Django Rest Framework Error: Unsupported Media Type: 415

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

Clicking on the like buttons is throwing the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

The code is supposed to submit the like action, retrieve the like counts and return the new serialized data. After doing some debugging on chrome, it looks like there is something wrong in the request header as when I inserted a print statement as the first line to the view function, it was never printed on the console, which indicates the error happens before the code makes it to the backend. But, I have set all the required headers, to the best of my knowledge. Searching online did not help either. So, here I am.

Here is the Vanilla JavaScript code:

```
function handleLikeButtons(){
let likeButtonsEls    = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='likeBtn-']")
likeButtonsEls.forEach( (likeBtn) => {
    likeBtn.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Submit the like
        const method = "POST"
        const url = likeBtn.getAttribute("data-like-endpoint")
        const headerOptions = "json"
        const commentId = likeBtn.getAttribute("data-comment-id")
        const data = JSON.stringify({"id": commentId, "action": "like"})
        // createXHRRequest(method, url, data, updateLikeCount, commentId, headerOptions)
        createXHRRequest(method, url, data, null, commentId,  headerOptions)
        })

    })
}

function createXHRRequest(method, url, data=null, callbackFn, extraData = null, headerOptions = null){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const responseType = "json"
    // console.log(`endpoint: ${url} - callbackFn: ${callbackFn} - extraData: ${extraData} - headerOptions: ${headerOptions}`)
    
if (!url && extraData){
        // Default behavior is to just load comments
        displayComments(null, extraData)
    }
    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method, url)

    if (headerOptions && headerOptions === 'json'){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "appliction/json")
        xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest")
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
    }
    xhr.onload = () =>{     
        if(xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300){
            handleLogicError(xhr)
        }
        if (callbackFn && extraData){
            callbackFn(xhr, extraData);
        }else if(callbackFn){
            callbackFn(xhr);
        }
        
    }
    xhr.onerror = ()=>{
        handleNetworkError(xhr)
    }
    if (data && url){
        if (data instanceof FormData ){
            for(let item of data.entries()){
                console.log(`${item[0]}: ${item[1]}`)
            }
        }
        
        xhr.send(data);

    } else if(url){
        xhr.send();

    }
}
```

and, here is my api view:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def comment_like_view(request, comment_id, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = BlogPostCommentSerializer(data = request.data)
    
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
        data = serializer.validated_data
        comment_id = data.get("id")
        action = data.get("action")
        qs = Comment.objects.filter(id = comment_id)
        if not qs.exists():
            return Response({"message": "No comment here to like"}, status=401)

        obj = qs.first()

        if action == 'like':
            obj.likes.add(request.user)
        elif action == 'unlike':
            obj.likes.remove(request.user)
        
        comment_serializer = serializer(obj)

        return Response(comment_serializer.data , status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And, the serializer:

```
class CommentActionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    action = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_action(self, value):
        value = value.lower().strip()
        if not value in LIKE_ACTIONS:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a valid action")

        return value
```

Do you know What's causing the 415 error message and how to resolve it?

Comment: I see a typo in 
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "appliction/json")`
It should be application and not appliction.

Comment: You have eagle eyes! typos are probably responsible for hours of wasted life for every programmer